# Зачем нужен __new__ и каково его практическое применение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Зачем нужен `__new__` в Python разработке и когда его использовать?

[Здесь есть](https://twitter.com/1st1/status/1160956824822194178) хороший комментарий в 2-х словах, что такое магический метод `__new__`: *статический метод, вызывается когда создается экземпляр класса*. В общем, сначала он, потом `__init__`, думаю верно понял.

Стыдно признаться, но ни разу не видел на практике применения этого магического метода, даже на простом игрушечном примере это выглядит излишним.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Creating Instance"
        instance = super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return instance

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def bar(self):
        pass
```

Может ли кто-то привести простой пример, где есть обоснованное использование `__new__` и объяснить зачем он нужен и когда его нужно использовать?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Из [официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> [`__new__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)
>   is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types (like int,
>   str, or tuple) to customize instance creation. It is also commonly
>   overridden in custom metaclasses in order to customize class creation.
>
> ---

[Здесь приведены примеры реального применения метода `__new__()`](https://howto.lintel.in/python-__new__-magic-method-explained/):

## Singleton

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None  # Keep instance reference 

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
```

проверка:

```
In [26]: s1 = Singleton()

In [27]: s2 = Singleton()

In [28]: s1 is s2
Out[28]: True
```

---

Пример использования в модуле [pathlib](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pathlib.py#L627-L635) (из стандартной библиотеки в Python 3.x):

```
class PurePath(object):
    ...

    def __new__(cls, *args):
        """Construct a PurePath from one or several strings and or existing
        PurePath objects.  The strings and path objects are combined so as
        to yield a canonicalized path, which is incorporated into the
        new PurePath object.
        """
        if cls is PurePath:
            cls = PureWindowsPath if os.name == 'nt' else PurePosixPath
        return cls._from_parts(args)
```

---

**NOTE:** если вам интересны примеры реального и правильного использования методов / функций в Python, то лучше подсмотреть как их используют авторы стандартной библиотеки Python:

- зайдите в директорию `<Python_installation>/Lib` и поищите в каких файлах присутствует интересующий вас метод: `def __new__`:

  ```
  C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3\Lib>grep -l "def __new__(" *.py
  _py_abc.py
  _pydecimal.py
  _pyio.py
  _threading_local.py
  abc.py
  codecs.py
  datetime.py
  enum.py
  fractions.py
  functools.py
  pathlib.py
  pstats.py
  sre_constants.py
  ssl.py
  turtle.py
  typing.py
  weakref.py
  ```
- открываете найденные файлы в редакторе, находите интересующие вас строки и изучаете примеры использования от создателей Python...

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ. Браво.